# How to modify css in visual composer

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to modify the css style of the word (button) "All" in Post Grid filter of Wordpress plugin Visual Composer...I'm able to do it for all the words of filtered categories but not for the specified one "All"...Firebug show me that style: `<span data-vc-grid-filter-value="*">All</span>` where I suppose the symbol * define all the words of categories...Anyone knows how can I modify that style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without example code it is always hard to answer.

Maybe this helps:

```
span[data-vc-grid-filter-value]:first-child {
    font-weight: 700; /* just an example adjustment */
}
```

I assumed that "All" is the first element in a series of elements. If this selector does not work, try to go more specific (e.g. li > span[data-vc-grid-filter-value]).

If you can provide a sample of the page, where this element is located, and the corresponding CSS, then the answer may be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you Muka your answear is helpful... I solved the issue giving the right style to the following selector class.vc_grid-filter > .vc_grid-filter-item:first-child

Comment: I'm happy that it was helpful! :)